# Не работает функция mail() в скрипте?

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть сервак (CentOS 7) на нём установлена виртуальная машина Битрикс, на которой работает коробка CRM. После очередного ***супер мега пупер*** обновления отвалилась всякая отправка почты. После ковыряния конфигов и чтения форумов ( все статьи сильно устарели, так как виртуальная машина уже 7!) подправил конфиг (***bitrixenv.ini***) :

```
;sendmail_path = msmtp -t -i
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

И о чудо, из консоли письма уходят по команде:

```
php -r "mail('admin@test.ru', 'Test', 'Test');"
```

Внимание вопрос! Почему в с корня сайта в test.php письма не уходят (скрипт зависает до 504)? Содержание файла:

```
$result = mail("xkav@bitrix.ru", "TEST", "TEST", "From: test@mail.ru\r\n");
var_dump($result);
```

Логи файла msmtp.log:

```
Feb 26 17:00:03 host=smtp.yandex.ru tls=on auth=on user=info@test.ru 

from=info@test.ru recipients=admin@test.ru smtpstatus=554 smtpmsg='554 5.7.0 Failed to authorize the sender 1551189603-fRuatm3cyB-037m551h 1551189603-PEQME1I1IE-02aqPLvt' errormsg='the server did not accept the mail' exitcode=EX_UNAVAILABLE
Feb 26 17:12:37 host=smtp.yandex.ru tls=on auth=on user=info@test.ru from=info@test.ru recipients=admin@test.ru smtpstatus=554 smtpmsg='554 5.7.0 Failed to authorize the sender 1551190357-QWdxVjBzbe-CbBeN9J0 1551190357-w62lOC3Fir-Cak8XANP' errormsg='the server did not accept the mail' exitcode=EX_UNAVAILABLE
Feb 26 17:12:39 host=smtp.yandex.ru tls=on auth=on user=info@test.ru from=info@test.ru recipients=admin@test.ru smtpstatus=554 smtpmsg='554 5.7.0 Failed to authorize the sender 1551190359-0bDXDBoMVB-CdmeYJpO 1551190359-Z3pRkBVvdh-CckqFTgS' errormsg='the server did not accept the mail' exitcode=EX_UNAVAILABLE
Feb 26 17:14:02 host=smtp.yandex.ru tls=on auth=on user=info@test.ru from=info@test.ru recipients=admin@test.ru mailsize=957 smtpstatus=250 smtpmsg='250 2.0.0 Ok: queued on smtp3p.mail.yandex.net as 1551190442-2ppu0r6Wak-E2gm2iR6' exitcode=EX_OK
Feb 26 17:14:03 host=smtp.yandex.ru tls=on auth=on user=info@test.ru from=info@test.ru recipients=admin@test.ru mailsize=873 smtpstatus=250 smtpmsg='250 2.0.0 Ok: queued on smtp4o.mail.yandex.net as 1551190443-l4HzALy1GG-E3Qqj7UX' exitcode=EX_OK
Feb 26 17:14:53 host=smtp.yandex.ru tls=on auth=on user=info@test.ru from=info@test.ru recipients=admin@test.ru smtpstatus=554 smtpmsg='554 5.7.0 Failed to authorize the sender 1551190493-hmonlVSexL-ErB0jp98 1551190493-Dq9wDQnvMI-EqE8xoJl' errormsg='the server did not accept the mail' exitcode=EX_UNAVAILABLE
Feb 26 17:14:56 host=smtp.yandex.ru tls=on auth=on user=info@test.ru from=info@test.ru recipients=admin@test.ru smtpstatus=554 smtpmsg='554 5.7.0 Failed to authorize the sender 1551190496-6PmUzDXsdc-EuaWP5k8 1551190496-Vm5qS6N8FS-Euq4dvpS' errormsg='the server did not accept the mail' exitcode=EX_UNAVAILABLE
Feb 26 17:15:37 host=smtp.yandex.ru tls=on auth=on user=info@test.ru from=info@test.ru recipients=admin@test.ru smtpstatus=554 smtpmsg='554 5.7.0 Failed to authorize the sender 1551190537-2FeHZuIenY-Fbk0lZS2 1551190537-9MtZJgoKP2-Fbkqc5BK' errormsg='the server did not accept the mail' exitcode=EX_UNAVAILABLE
Feb 26 17:16:13 host=smtp.yandex.ru tls=on auth=on user=info@test.ru from=info@test.ru recipients=***@yandex.ru mailsize=843 smtpstatus=250 smtpmsg='250 2.0.0 Ok: queued on smtp4o.mail.yandex.net as 1551190573-9cxKuJegOR-GCQixFgW' exitcode=EX_OK
Feb 26 17:16:28 host=smtp.yandex.ru tls=on auth=on user=info@test.ru from=info@test.ru recipients=admin@test.ru smtpstatus=554 smtpmsg='554 5.7.0 Failed to authorize the sender 1551190588-1IxK6i581Q-GS7CFWUd 1551190588-wxndNEqoZC-GR4e6JKj' errormsg='the server did not accept the mail' exitcode=EX_UNAVAILABLE
Feb 26 17:17:36 host=smtp.yandex.ru tls=on auth=on user=info@test.ru from=info@test.ru recipients=admin@test.ru smtpstatus=554 smtpmsg='554 5.7.0 Failed to authorize the sender 1551190656-7KCU4zAps1-HaXmZcAU 1551190656-KpG9eeGBU5-HaEiLNxD' errormsg='the server did not accept the mail' exitcode=EX_UNAVAILABLE
Feb 26 17:17:58 host=smtp.yandex.ru tls=on auth=on user=info@test.ru from=info@test.ru recipients=***@mail.ru smtpstatus=554 smtpmsg='554 5.7.1 [2] Message rejected under suspicion of SPAM; https://ya.cc/1IrBc 1551190678-vjtBwtXIlG-Hq4WRT3Y' errormsg='the server did not accept the mail' exitcode=EX_UNAVAILABLE
Feb 26 17:18:02 host=smtp.yandex.ru tls=on auth=on user=info@test.ru from=info@test.ru recipients=***@yandex.ru smtpstatus=554 smtpmsg='554 5.7.1 [2] Message rejected under suspicion of SPAM; https://ya.cc/1IrBc 1551190682-6UbGvzFHeS-Hwqq0h6e' errormsg='the server did not accept the mail' exitcode=EX_UNAVAILABLE
фев 26 17:18:03 host=smtp.yandex.ru tls=on auth=on user=info@test.ru from=info@test.ru recipients=***@mail.ru mailsize=24997 smtpstatus=250 smtpmsg='250 2.0.0 Ok: queued on smtp1p.mail.yandex.net as 1551190683-Dp6XypmYLg-I348bNrW' exitcode=EX_OK
Feb 26 17:18:06 host=smtp.yandex.ru tls=on auth=on user=info@test.ru from=info@test.ru recipients=***@***.com smtpstatus=554 smtpmsg='554 5.7.1 [2] Message rejected under suspicion of SPAM; https://ya.cc/1IrBc 1551190686-cKc5fXX1Vg-I3a0TMaD' errormsg='the server did not accept the mail' exitcode=EX_UNAVAILABLE
Feb 26 17:18:11 host=smtp.yandex.ru tls=on auth=on user=info@test.ru from=info@test.ru recipients=***@yandex.ru smtpstatus=554 smtpmsg='554 5.7.1 [2] Message rejected under suspicion of SPAM; https://ya.cc/1IrBc 1551190691-HKBQfLH2wd-I7qKRllN' errormsg='the server did not accept the mail' exitcode=EX_UNAVAILABLE
Feb 26 17:18:15 host=smtp.yandex.ru tls=on auth=on user=info@test.ru from=info@test.ru recipients=***@rambler.ru smtpstatus=554 smtpmsg='554 5.7.1 [1] Message rejected under suspicion of SPAM; https://ya.cc/1IrBc 1551190695-FMkLi0ViVV-IBa4bf8R' errormsg='the server did not accept the mail' exitcode=EX_UNAVAILABLE
Feb 26 17:18:16 host=smtp.yandex.ru tls=on auth=on user=info@test.ru from=info@test.ru recipients=***@***.ru smtpstatus=554 smtpmsg='554 5.7.1 [2] Message rejected under suspicion of SPAM; https://ya.cc/1IrBc 1551190696-JOuMqgmi6v-IF4i4iKg' errormsg='the server did not accept the mail' exitcode=EX_UNAVAILABLE
Feb 26 17:18:55 host=smtp.yandex.ru tls=on auth=on user=info@test.ru from=info@test.ru recipients=***@mail.ru mailsize=10493214 smtpstatus=250 smtpmsg='250 2.0.0 Ok: queued on smtp4p.mail.yandex.net as 1551190735-Q4QFSX6RWj-Imk4Kirs' exitcode=EX_OK
```

Какие то уходят а какие то нет

Comment: А отправляете всегда с одного ящика или с разных?

Comment: Скиньте ваш конфиг-файл msmtp если настраивали через него.

Comment: @NikolajSarry проблему решил сменой хостинга отправителя. С яндекса на бегет. Так как в яндекс просто в бан посылал нормальные письма. Сегодня тестирую. С настройками всё ок.